# Checking for empty "href" and appending anchor text if it is empty

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have a function in `Javascript`, that is supposed to iterate through a table of links to check if an `href` is empty. If the `href` is empty, it adds a block of text between the anchors to indicate no link added yet. The code I have is below:

```
function isWorking(){
    //Variable declaration
    var anchor, rows, i, link, x, y;
    anchor = document.getElementById("myTable");
    rows = anchor.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    for(i = 0; i < (rows.length - 1); i++){
        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("A");
        link = x.getAttribute("href");
        y = link.getElementsByTagName("FONT")[0];
        if(link = ""){
            y.innerHTML += "<b><font color=red> (not added yet)</font></b>";
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, it doesn't really do anything. I'm not very proficient enough in `Javascript` so I am having a really hard time understanding what may need to change to make this code work correctly.

Edit: So here is an example of the table I'm using in HTML:

```
    <table id="myTable">
            <tr><td><a href="" target="_blank"><font size="4" color="white">C</a></font></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a href="" target="_blank"><font size="4" color="white">A</a></font></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a href="" target="_blank"><font size="4" color="white">B</a></font></td></tr>
    </table>
```

In the example I include 3 blank links (A, B, and C). Since each links `href` is empty, I want to append the text with a the text in my if in the code.

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: None at all. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: `if(link = ""){` should be `if(link == ""){`

Comment: If you could put together a snippet with sample HTML, that would help. One error that immediately pops out is that last if block: if(link = "") -- single equals sign is an assignment.  == or === would both work, I would get into the habit of using === because you rarely want type coalescence in your equality boolean evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(link = "")` is invalid.. You are defining the value by the `=` operator. It should be `if(link == "")`.. Your code can also be minified - don't really know what you're defining the table and rows for. Just to get the a link? A better way:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv a'),
// gets all a links inside [mydiv] div...
i, href;

for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  href = links[i].getAttribute('href');
  //check the length of href.. is it less than 1 or is a space
  if(href.trim().length < 1) {
    alert(i + ' is null: ' + href);
  }

}
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/sadikyalcin/tLcn7fee/)

Comment: For the if(href.length < 1 || href === ' ')  condition, wouldn't it make more sense to do if(href.trim().length < 1) ? Or === 0 for that matter?

Comment: @Mic yes actually that would be better. Edited - I prefer using less than operator :)

Comment: Your code is pretty much what Im looking for (after some small changes) but for some reason, it doesn't work with IE. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: Which version? Check support for queryselectorall

Comment: IE11, I just found out that I need to use the following meta tag for it to work:  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Answer (score 0):

Below line has error

```
link = x.getAttribute("href");
```

`x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("A");` This statement returns a collection of elements. So to use the function getAttribute, you should apply it on element like below

```
if(x.length>0)
link = x[0].getAttribute("href");
```

Your next statements needs modifications accordingly. link.GetElementByTagName will not work as the link does not have any DOM element but just a string value.

You can try it live [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_getattribute1)

Answer (score 0):

quick and simple:

```
function checkTableHref() {
        var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            if (elem[i].getAttribute("href") == "") {
                alert(null);
            }
            else {
                alert("Not Null");
            }
        }
    };
```

and html:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" target="_blank"><font size="4" color="white">C</a></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" target="_blank"><font size="4" color="white">A</a></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" target="_blank"><font size="4" color="white">B</a></font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the == operator to compare.

```
<input type=button id="links" text="Switch Mode" onclick="toggle_visibility()" class="" value="Check Link">
<br>
<a id='not_null' href=""></a>
```

```js
function toggle_visibility() {    
         var x = document.getElementById('not_null');
         link = x.getAttribute("href");

         if (link =="")//Here you are missing
         {           
         alert("true! This is null");
         }      

  }
```